# C# Emgu CV - how to use cuda in dnn

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

```
public static void DetectObjects(Bitmap bitmapImage)
    {
        
        Image<Bgr, byte> image;

        image = bitmapImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();

        Mat input = DnnInvoke.BlobFromImage(image, 1 / 255.0, swapRB: true);

        _netModel.SetInput(input);

        Mat output = _netModel.Forward();

    }

    private static Net _netModel = DnnInvoke.ReadNetFromDarknet("B:/yolov3.cfg.txt", "B:/yolov3.weights");
```

The project has EmguCV version 4.4.0.4099 and the CUDA module of the same version.

As a result, I need the function to perform calculations on the GPU.

How many did not search about this, I did not find suitable information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems enough to use

```
_netModel.SetPreferableBackend(Emgu.CV.Dnn.Backend.Cuda);
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/077a1d69c48e4cdb9957d167b7000b98)

Comment: as far as I remember they also have a supported backend property somewhere laying around. So it could be usefull checking this array before setting the backend